# iam having a issue when using .toString() on an item in the array with jquery

Tags: jquery, object-to-string

The probelm i am having is when using .toString() it does not work, but if I wrap the value with jQuery ($) then i get a jquery object instead. It would be good if there is a solution to both working with object.toString() or getting the value in jQuery object.

```
rows.each(function () {
    var val = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($.inArray(val, levels) == -1) {
        levels.unshift(val);
    }
});

$(levels).each(function (i, value) {

    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

        var tmp = value.toString();

        if (x == 1) {
            console.log("level 2: " + tmp.substring(0, tmp.lastIndexOf('-')));
        }
        else if (x == 2) {
            console.log("level 1: " + tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf('-')));
        }
        else {
            console.log("level 3: " + tmp.toString());
        }

        console.log(tmp);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `toString()` twice (when setting the `tmp` variable *and* when you're using the `tmp` variable)? Also, what HTML is this working with?

Comment: Also: what are the values? DOM Elements? Javascript objects? The reason the `jquery(X).toString` works is because `jQuery()` returns a jQuery object, which has a `toString` function (it has many others, like `each()` and `append()` etc), if the object/element you are trying to `toString` has no such method.. it can never work.

Comment: the values in the levels array are id's from the <tr> tag, but i only save the id's. It is included now in the question.

Comment: all i want to do is use the substring() method. I am not using it in the HTML, is used within the .js methods

Comment: how do i retrieve the value from the $object ?

Comment: i have tried the typeof method on the tmp variable and it is a string, but how come I dont get the substring() method ?

Comment: the solution was to use this instead of value! thanx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `this` instead of `value`!